# Como deixar sidenav e toolbar fixas com angular material

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

Quero deixar fixo a sidenav e o toolbar do Angular Material, e o conteúdo da aplicação ficar no restante da página. Na minha index.html estou usando a diretiva ng-view pra renderizar. Tenho uma pagina menu.html que está a sidenav e a tollbar, e outras paginas, como home.html. Como faço pra deixar fixo em todas as paginas a minha sidenav e a toolbar?

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso esse template para ter o menu lateral e um toolbar fixo.. alterando somente as rotas no angularjs para view.

```html
<body ng-app="deluxApp" layout="row">
 <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')" >
   <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
  <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">toolbar fixo</h1>
   </md-toolbar>
   <md-content>
  <!--  meu menu -->     
   </md-content>
 </md-sidenav>
 <section layout="column" flex>
  <md-toolbar>
   <div layout="row" layout-padding layout-margin layout-fill layout-align="end center">
    <md-button href="/logout" class="md-icon-button">
     <md-icon class="md-36" layout-align="right">power_settings_new</md-icon>
    </md-button>
   </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content layout="column" flex>  
   <div class="container" ng-view="" layout="column" flex>          
   </div>
  </md-content>
 </section>
</body>
```

Espero que isso te ajude.